# HTTPS not responding in Centos 7 server

Tags: centos, ssl, https

I use a commercial godaddy standard SSL server; I tried stop firewalld and iptables, but still no change. It works fine with HTTP, but is not responding with HTTPS. No ssl_error logs. I've been stuck for hours on this problem. My config is below.

I'm using Apache 2.4.6.

These are my **listening ports** for localhost:

```
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

**ssl.conf**

```
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName mydomain.com:443

ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/3e3f335d2b598900.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/virtualist.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd.conf**

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: Any iptables firewall rules?

Comment: I dont use iptable but i activated 443 https in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem today. It wasnt a problem of my server. After i tried with self signed key and after it worked, i started suspecting about my domain. Then i call the call center of godaddy and they said to me you should update your A record with your servers ip from domain settings. After i did this my https started working. Thanks to everyone who tried to help :)